# Random Key Generator In Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, generator

I've made a random key generator, That can even be used for creating a new password for you.

```
import random
chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890"
while 1:
    key_len = int(input("What length would you like your key to be?: "))
    key_count = int(input("How many keys would you like?: "))
    for x in range(0,key_count):
        key = ""
        for x in range(0,key_len):
            key_char = random.choice(chars)
            key = key + key_char
        print("Here's your key: ",key)
```

Output:

```
What length would you like your key to be?: 4
How many keys would you like?: 1
Here's your key: 1337
What length would you like your key to be?:
```

Comment: You should include the error you get : SyntaxError: invalid syntax `for x in range(0,key_len)`.

Comment: I forgot about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for x in range(0,key_len)
```

you forgot to put colon to end. After I put colon code worked for me

```
for x in range(0,key_len):
```

Comment: I probably accidentally removed the colon, When i tried to optimize the code. But otherwise thanks for pointing that out. :)